# Google map mileage function to return mileage between two addresses

Tags: php, google-maps, yii2, google-distancematrix-api

For each loop quit working.

```
public static function getMiles($to, $from)
{

    $from = urlencode($from);
    $to = urlencode($to);
    $data = file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=$from&destinations=$to&key=MyKey");

    $time = 0;
    $distance = 0;

    /* return as an object for easier notation */
    $json=json_decode( $data, false );
    $origins = $json->origin_addresses;
    $destinations=$json->destination_addresses;

    /*  if there are multiple rows, use a loop and `$rows[$i]` etc */
    $elements=$json->rows[0]->elements;

    foreach( $elements as $i => $obj ){
    } 
    //extract the mileage as meters
    $miles = $obj->distance->value;

    //converting the meters to miles
    $distance= round(($miles * '0.000621371192'), 1);
    //returning miles
    return $distance;

}
```

The end result is to return mileage between 2 addresses. 
Error message is "'Invalid argument supplied for foreach()'".

Comment: that means that the `$elements=$json->rows[0]->elements` is not an array try to check what is inside it using `print_r()`

Comment: When I add the following:            /* return as an object for easier notation */
        $json=json_decode( $data, false );
        $origins = $json->origin_addresses;
        $destinations=$json->destination_addresses;
       echo "$destinations";
        die();  The result is "array".   when I use the print_r ($destinations);  I get a blank screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it is my fault.  Upon further digging, I was able to determine that my credit card had expired.  Reset my expire date and code is working again.
Thanks for helping me Muhammad Omer Aslam for pointing me to get the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your function works without problem on my end. I actually only get this "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" error when I obfuscate my API key from the Distance Matrix API request.

Try running the code below with a **valid** API key (replacing "YOUR_KEY"):

```
function getMiles($to, $from)
{
    $from = urlencode($from);
    $to = urlencode($to);
    $data = file_get_contents("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=$from&destinations=$to&key=YOUR_KEY");

    $time = 0;
    $distance = 0;

    /* return as an object for easier notation */
    $json=json_decode( $data, false );
    $origins = $json->origin_addresses;
    $destinations=$json->destination_addresses;
    /*  if there are multiple rows, use a loop and `$rows[$i]` etc */
    $elements=$json->rows[0]->elements;

    foreach( $elements as $i => $obj ){
    } 
    //extract the mileage as meters
    $miles = $obj->distance->value;

    //converting the meters to miles
    $distance= round(($miles * '0.000621371192'), 1);
    //returning miles
    return $distance;
}

echo "\nMiles: " . getMiles("paris,france", "berlin,germany");
```

The output you get should be `Miles: 659`.

I recommend you go through [these](https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started#procedures) [guides](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/get-api-key) to double-check your key, project and billing account are all in good standing.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Evan, it was the billing account

Comment: Glad to hear you resolved the issue after re-enabling billing. :)